# Get a ordered JSON tree from Postgres

Tags: json, postgresql, recursion, tree

I'm working on a dynamic menu and I need to get a JSON tree with data to build the options in the interface (using CSS, HTML and JS), based on the constraints defined in three tables ( [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/e0f7b/2) still has postgres 9.6, but I'm using postgres 15.0 )

The general idea is to first find the nodes that point to a file (***file IS NOT NULL***), which are active (***status = A***) and which are from subsystem 1 (***id_subsystem = 1***), as long as the user 1 (***id_user = 1***) is also active (***status = A***) and has access permission (according to the ***users_modules*** table)

With these records, it would be enough to find each parent recursively related and add them to the tree, but keeping the order defined by the **group_order** field

### **users**

```sql
CREATE TABLE users (
  id SMALLINT NOT NULL,
  name CHARACTER VARYING(20) NOT NULL,
  status CHAR(1) NOT NULL
);
```

| id | name | status |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | John Doe | A |
| 2 | Jane Doe | A |
| 3 | Duh Doe | I |

### **modules**

```sql
CREATE TABLE modules (
  id SMALLINT NOT NULL,
  id_subsystem SMALLINT NOT NULL,
  id_master SMALLINT,
  group_order SMALLINT NOT NULL,
  label CHARACTER VARYING(30) NOT NULL,
  file CHARACTER VARYING(30),
  icon CHARACTER VARYING(20),
  status CHAR(1) NOT NULL
);
INSERT INTO
  modules
VALUES
  (1,1,NULL,1,'Dashboard','dashboard','dashboard','A'),
  (2,1,NULL,2,'Registrations',NULL,'cabinet','A'),
  (3,1,2,1,'Customers','customers',NULL,'A'),
  (4,1,2,2,'Suppliers','suppliers',NULL,'A'),
  (5,1,2,3,'Products','products',NULL,'A'),
  (6,1,2,4,'Staff',NULL,NULL,'A'),
  (7,1,6,1,'Countries','countries',NULL,'A'),
  (8,1,6,2,'States','states',NULL,'A'),
  (9,1,6,3,'Cities','cities',NULL,'A'),
  (10,1,6,4,'Means of contacts',NULL,NULL,'A'),
  (11,1,10,1,'Electronic contacts','electronic_contacts',NULL,'A'),
  (12,1,10,2,'Phone contacts','phone_contacts',NULL,'A'),
  (13,1,10,3,'Deprecated contacts','deprecated_contacts',NULL,'I'),
  (14,1,NULL,3,'Settings','settings','sliders','A'),
  (15,2,NULL,1,'Dashboard','dashboard','dashboard','A'),
  (16,2,NULL,2,'Financial',NULL,'cash','A'),
  (17,2,16,1,'Bills to pay','bills_to_pay',NULL,'A'),
  (18,2,16,2,'Bills to receive','bills_to_receive',NULL,'A');
```

| id | id_subsystem | id_master | order | label | file | icon | status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | NULL | 1 | Dashboard | dashboard | dashboard | A |
| 2 | 1 | NULL | 2 | Registrations | NULL | cabinet | A |
| 3 | 1 | 2 | 1 | Customers | customers | NULL | A |
| 4 | 1 | 2 | 2 | Suppliers | suppliers | NULL | A |
| 5 | 1 | 2 | 3 | Products | products | NULL | A |
| 6 | 1 | 2 | 4 | Staff | NULL | NULL | A |
| 7 | 1 | 6 | 1 | Countries | countries | NULL | A |
| 8 | 1 | 6 | 2 | States | states | NULL | A |
| 9 | 1 | 6 | 3 | Cities | cities | NULL | A |
| 10 | 1 | 6 | 4 | Means of contacts | NULL | NULL | A |
| 11 | 1 | 10 | 1 | Electronic contacts | electronic_contacts | NULL | A |
| 12 | 1 | 10 | 2 | Phone contacts | phone_contacts | NULL | A |
| 13 | 1 | 10 | 3 | Deprecated contacts | deprecated_contacts | NULL | I |
| 14 | 1 | NULL | 3 | Settings | settings | sliders | A |
| 15 | 2 | NULL | 1 | Dashboard | dashboard | dashboard | A |
| 16 | 2 | NULL | 2 | Financial | NULL | cash | A |
| 17 | 2 | 16 | 1 | Bills to pay | bills_to_pay | NULL | A |
| 18 | 2 | 16 | 2 | Bills to receive | bills_to_receive | NULL | A |

### **users_modules**

```sql
CREATE TABLE users_modules (
  id_user SMALLINT NOT NULL,
  id_module SMALLINT NOT NULL
);
INSERT INTO
  users_modules
VALUES
  (1,1),
  (1,3),
  (1,4),
  (1,5),
  (1,7),
  (1,8),
  (1,11),
  (1,12);
```

| id_user | id_module |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 3 |
| 1 | 4 |
| 1 | 5 |
| 1 | 7 |
| 1 | 8 |
| 1 | 11 |
| 1 | 12 |

I created the query below and it seems to be pretty close to solving the problem, but I still can't figure out what it is

```sql
WITH RECURSIVE
  sub1 (id_master,sub) AS
  (
    (

/*

  THE FIRST PART OF A RECURSIVE CTE IS FOR NON-RECURSIVE DATA

  HERE I GET ALL THE RECORDS THAT POINT TO A FILE THAT CAN BE ACCESSED BY THE USER, BUT ONLY IF IT DOESN'T HAVE THE ROOT AS THE PARENT

*/
      SELECT
        B.id_master,
        JSONB_AGG(
          JSONB_BUILD_OBJECT(
            'icon',B.icon,
            'label',B.label,
            'module',B.file
          )
          ORDER BY
            B.group_order
        ) AS sub
      FROM
        (
          SELECT
            X.id_module
          FROM
            users_modules X
          INNER JOIN
            users Y
          ON
            X.id_user=Y.id
          WHERE
            X.id_user=1 AND
            Y.status='A'
        ) A
      INNER JOIN
        modules B
      ON
        A.id_module=B.id
      WHERE
        B.id_master IS NOT NULL AND
        B.id_subsystem=1 AND
        B.status='A'
      GROUP BY
        B.id_master

    )
    UNION ALL
    (

/*

  THE SECOND PART OF A RECURSIVE CTE IS FOR RECURSIVE DATA

  HERE I ASSEMBLE THE TREE CONNECTING ALL FINAL NODES AND BRANCHES POINTED RECURSIVELY

*/
      SELECT
        A.id_master,
        JSONB_BUILD_OBJECT(
          'icon',A.icon,
          'label',A.label,
          'sub',B.sub
        ) AS sub
      FROM
        modules A
      INNER JOIN
        sub1 B
      ON
        A.id=B.id_master
      WHERE
        A.status='A'
      ORDER BY
        A.group_order

    )
  )

SELECT
  JSONB_AGG(sub ORDER BY group_order)
FROM
  (
    SELECT
      sub,
      group_order
    FROM
      (
        (

/*

  TYING AT THE ROOT ALL KNOTS POINTING TO THE ROOT

*/
          SELECT
            JSONB_BUILD_OBJECT(
              'icon',A.icon,
              'label',A.label,
              'sub',B.sub
            ) AS sub,
            A.group_order
          FROM
            modules A
          INNER JOIN
            sub1 B
          ON
            A.id=B.id_master
          WHERE
            A.id_master IS NULL AND
            A.id_subsystem=1 AND
            A.status='A'

        )
        UNION ALL
        (

/*

  ADDING ALL USER ACCESSIBLE FILE NODES THAT HAVE ROOT AS THE PARENT

*/
          SELECT
            JSONB_BUILD_OBJECT(
              'icon',B.icon,
              'label',B.label,
              'module',B.file
            ) AS sub,
            B.group_order
          FROM
            (
              SELECT
                A.id_module
              FROM
                users_modules A
              INNER JOIN
                modules B
              ON
                A.id_module=B.id
              WHERE
                A.id_user=1 AND
                B.id_master IS NULL AND
                B.status='A'
              GROUP BY
                A.id_module
            ) A
          INNER JOIN
            modules B
          ON
            A.id_module=B.id AND
            B.status='A'

        )
      ) sub2
  ) sub3
```

What I get is this:

```json
[
  {
    "icon": "dashboard",
    "label": "Dashboard",
    "module": "dashboard"
  },
  {
    "icon": "cabinet",
    "label": "Registrations",
    "sub":
      [
        {
          "icon": null,
          "label": "Customers",
          "module": "customers"
        },
        {
          "icon": null,
          "label": "Suppliers",
          "module": "suppliers"
        },
        {
          "icon": null,
          "label": "Products",
          "module": "products"
        }
      ]
  },
  {
    "icon": "cabinet",
    "label": "Registrations",
    "sub":
      {
        "icon": null,
        "label": "Staff",
        "sub":
          [
            {
              "icon": null,
              "label": "Countries",
              "module": "countries"
            },
              {
              "icon": null,
              "label": "States",
              "module": "states"
            }
          ]
      }
  },
  {
    "icon": "cabinet",
    "label": "Registrations",
    "sub":
      {
        "icon": null,
        "label": "Staff",
        "sub":
          {
            "icon": null,
            "label": "Means of contacts",
            "sub":
              [
                {
                  "icon": null,
                  "label": "Electronic contacts",
                  "module": "electronic_contacts"
                },
                {
                  "icon": null,
                  "label": "Phone contacts",
                  "module": "phone_contacts"
                }
              ]
          }
      }
  }
]
```

But what I need is this:

```json
[
  {
    "icon": "dashboard",
    "label": "Dashboard",
    "module": "dashboard"
  },
  {
    "icon": "cabinet",
    "label": "Registrations",
    "sub":
      [
        {
          "icon": null,
          "label": "Customers",
          "module": "customers"
        },
        {
          "icon": null,
          "label": "Suppliers",
          "module": "suppliers"
        },
        {
          "icon": null,
          "label": "Products",
          "module": "products"
        },
        {
          "icon": null,
          "label": "Staff",
          "sub":
            [
              {
                "icon": null,
                "label": "Countries",
                "module": "countries"
              },
                {
                "icon": null,
                "label": "States",
                "module": "states"
              },
              {
                "icon": null,
                "label": "Means of contacts",
                "sub":
                  [
                    {
                      "icon": null,
                      "label": "Electronic contacts",
                      "module": "electronic_contacts"
                    },
                    {
                      "icon": null,
                      "label": "Phone contacts",
                      "module": "phone_contacts"
                    }
                  ]
              }
            ]
        }
      ]
  },
  {
    "icon": "sliders",
    "label": "Settings",
    "module": "settings"
  }
]
```

Part of the members of the ***registrations*** node was not nested inside it and the ***settings*** node was lost

Almost there...

Comment: There is an interesting discussion about the problematic https://community.oracle.com/tech/developers/discussion/4494033/recursive-pl-sql-generation-of-hierarchical-json and https://paulzipblog.wordpress.com/2020/04/29/hierarchical-json-structures/, the solutions are for ORACLE but it may help to understand what you have to change in your code. (NB the solutions are not perfect because they don't support multiple root nodes but the fixes are not difficult)

Comment: Your problem comes from the fact that you crawl the tree bottom-up starting by the nodes corresponding to your criteria, that prevents the correct export. You should crawl top-down with "SEARCH DEPTH FIRST BY group_order SET rn" and filter out the results at the end, keeping the nodes on the path of the leafs corresponding to your criteria.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The query here below provides the expected result according to your data set :

```
WITH RECURSIVE list AS (
SELECT m.id_subsystem
     , p.id :: integer AS id_master
     , array_agg(m.id :: integer ORDER BY m.group_order) AS children_array
     , bool_and(NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM modules where id_master = m.id)) AS leaves_only
     , jsonb_build_object('icon', p.icon, 'label', p.label,'sub', jsonb_agg(jsonb_build_object('icon', m.icon, 'label', m.label, 'module', m.file) ORDER BY m.group_order)) AS module_hierarchy
  FROM modules m
  LEFT JOIN modules p
    ON p.id = m.id_master
 GROUP BY m.id_subsystem, p.id, p.icon, p.label
), tree AS (
SELECT id_subsystem
     , id_master
     , module_hierarchy
  FROM list
 WHERE leaves_only -- starts with the leaf modules
UNION ALL
SELECT t.id_subsystem
     , l.id_master
     , jsonb_set(l.module_hierarchy, array['sub', (array_position(l.children_array, t.id_master) - 1) :: text], t.module_hierarchy, true)
  FROM tree t
 INNER JOIN list l
    ON l.children_array @> array[t.id_master] -- bottom-up tree build
   AND l.id_subsystem = t.id_subsystem
 WHERE t.id_master IS NOT NULL
)
SELECT id_subsystem, jsonb_pretty(module_hierarchy->'sub')
  FROM tree
 WHERE id_master IS NULL
```

Some conditions are not implemented yet : status of the modules and users, users_modules relationship, but adding these conditions should not be a big deal.

This query provides the expected result only if there is only one branch with 2 levels or more which is the case in your data set. When there are 2  or more branches with 2 levels or more, we need to merge the branches all together with a dedicated aggregate function :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION jsonb_merge (x jsonb, y jsonb)
  RETURNS jsonb LANGUAGE sql IMMUTABLE AS $$
  SELECT jsonb_agg(
         CASE
           WHEN x.content->>'sub' IS NOT NULL AND y.content->>'sub' IS NOT NULL
           THEN (x.content - 'sub') || jsonb_build_object('sub', jsonb_merge(x.content->'sub', y.content->'sub'))
           WHEN x.content->>'sub' IS NOT NULL
           THEN x.content
           ELSE y.content
         END
         ORDER BY x.id
         )
    FROM jsonb_path_query(COALESCE(x, y), '$[*]') WITH ORDINALITY AS x(content, id)
   INNER JOIN jsonb_path_query(y, '$[*]') WITH ORDINALITY AS y(content, id)
      ON x.id = y.id
$$ ;

CREATE OR REPLACE AGGREGATE jsonb_merge(jsonb)
( stype = jsonb, sfunc = jsonb_merge) ;
```

This aggregate function cannot be called directly inside the recursive query because postgres doesn't accept aggregate functions in the recursive part of the query, but it can be called after :

```
WITH RECURSIVE list AS (
SELECT m.id_subsystem
     , p.id :: integer AS id_master
     , array_agg(m.id :: integer ORDER BY m.group_order) AS children_array
     , bool_and(NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM modules where id_master = m.id)) AS leaves_only
     , jsonb_build_object('icon', p.icon, 'label', p.label,'sub', jsonb_agg(jsonb_build_object('icon', m.icon, 'label', m.label, 'module', m.file) ORDER BY m.group_order)) AS module_hierarchy
  FROM modules m
  LEFT JOIN modules p
    ON p.id = m.id_master
 GROUP BY m.id_subsystem, p.id, p.icon, p.label
), tree AS (
SELECT id_subsystem
     , id_master
     , module_hierarchy
  FROM list
 WHERE leaves_only
UNION ALL
SELECT t.id_subsystem
     , l.id_master
     , jsonb_set(l.module_hierarchy, array['sub', (array_position(l.children_array, t.id_master) - 1) :: text], t.module_hierarchy, true)
  FROM tree t
 INNER JOIN list l
    ON l.children_array @> array[t.id_master]
   AND l.id_subsystem = t.id_subsystem
 WHERE t.id_master IS NOT NULL
)
SELECT id_subsystem
     , jsonb_pretty(jsonb_merge(module_hierarchy->'sub'))
  FROM tree
 WHERE id_master IS NULL
 GROUP BY id_subsystem
```

This query should work for any kind of trees with any levels.

see test result in [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/pNbo9ho9)

Comment: Edward, you are amazing! I've been trying to solve this for a long time... I really appreciate the help.